# Oracle SQL: select last n qualifiers of a delimited string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a delimited string in a column, and I want to select the last 5 qualifiers.  For example, in the below example i would like to get the result '3,4,5,6,7'.

```
select '1,2,3,4,5,6,7' as val from dual
```

I am currently fiddling with reversing the string and trying to do a regexp_substr (maybe in combination with a regexp_count and a row_number?) on it, but I can't quite figure it out yet.

I can find several similar threads, but can't find the answer for oracle sql yet. If I find the solution I will post it here!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+split+string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr('1,2,3,4,5,6,7', '([^,]+[,]?){5}$')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like :

```
select substr(val, instr(val, ',', -1, 5) + 1)
```

This simply finds the fifth occurrence of `','` starting from the right and then returns the string from that character on